# Symfony 3 ArrayCollection key search

Tags: symfony

If I have a variable of a type ArrayCollection how do I check if a key of a specific name exists in the collection including nesting. And if it does how do I get and change that value?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about Doctrines ArrayCollection `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`.

It does implement phps native `ArrayAccess` interface, so have a look at [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php). Just check like:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
$myCollection = new ArrayCollection(array('testKey' => 'testVal'));
var_dump(isset($myCollection['testKey']));
```

It does also implement its own method from the `Collection` interface.

```
/**
 * Checks whether the collection contains an element with the specified key/index.
 *
 * @param string|integer $key The key/index to check for.
 *
 * @return boolean TRUE if the collection contains an element with the specified key/index,
 *                 FALSE otherwise.
 */
public function containsKey($key);
```

For nested objects there is no build in method, you have to traverse the collection yourself like you would do with a normal array.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I found was to use the `toArray()` method in the `ArrayCollection` object and then use the `array_search` function:

```
$newArray = $arrayCollectionObject->toArray();
$keyThatIneed = array_search($value, $newArray);
```